# typescript: utility extension function with Partial not working

Tags: typescript

As seen here in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxAHgBUAaOAaTlBmBQBMBnOAa2AE8IE4S4BZSkanUaEA2mQC6APgAUEAEYArAFxdSYKBDAqypKjXrYUKgAoBDWJlMAbfD0kBKOAG8AsACg4nuPIUj1m8TgAXmd3L3C4ADponz8NMHFiMIjPaMi9FAMcZM8AX3d8t3cYVjBgLmDQjzhTFXoYKEwUAHMk6rkVFCQAWzlgKAL3dzQrU3pGAGEqzxgVQkqnGpUAclNl0g64AGY4QuS0HHqoJAxoaUdXas8QaRgAC0x6UmWYdec4TYAWACZd+2TCrkgA), I would like to create a small "functionnal" utility function but TS doesn't like very much what I am truing to do.
It complains about my argument being `not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<this["t"]>'`

```
export function x<T, K extends keyof T, M extends T[K]>(obj: T, prop: K, extension: Partial<M>) {
    obj[prop] = {
        ...obj[prop],
        ...extension
    }
}

type T = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

class C {
  t: T = { a: 'a', b: 3 }

  constructor() {
    x(this, 't', { b: 42 }) // error is here
  }
}
```

Is there a trick for this ? Maybe `ThisType` but not too sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither I do not know why this happens, but it is fixable by using `x(this as C, 't', { b: 42 })`.

Also, I would change few things around to prevent weird bugs:

```
/** From type `O` extract only keys that match type `T` */
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
    [P in keyof O]: O[P] extends T ? P : never;
}[keyof O];

export function x<T, K extends KeysOfType<T, Record<any, any>>>(obj: T, prop: K, extension: Partial<T[K]>) {
    obj[prop] = {
        ...obj[prop], // Prevent error, if obj is not initialized yet
        ...extension,
    }
}

type T = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

class C {
  v = 3;
  t: T = { a: 'a', b: 3 }
  t2: T = { a: 'a', b: 3 }

  constructor() {
    x(this as C, 'v', { b: 42 });  // Error
    x(this as C, 't', { b: 42 });  // OK
    x(this as C, 't2', { b: 42 }); // OK
  }
}
```

[playground](http://DgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKuCAeJAaKaAfFALxQDeAsAFACQA2gApQCWAdlANbwD2KUSALoAuAU0FQIAD2AQ2AEwQEoAfijNRbCADcIAJwDcNAL71uIPgMFHqNaWB57gUFAFc2AY2AseHKVjR8GEkZOUVYeGR0TAD8ACUID0d5LABDNhB8dJBCXIAKHgAjACtRQKgwPR4wURh8aVk2BB82UUZUpxZUgBsA+hhBQgBKChoocagi4vpK6okyKmoJ5agAOnWpmaqwQVwxlfH11Ya5Zt89pYnjExoaUEhlBf3U0QRgPXYAcwvxws1XAC2hX0N1s1A83VSCCUAGFRpdtKQoABmGzjYBlJHkKAvKAAclSePwfxRUGul2AACZMQscaICUSoCTkWTbpckk13q4vI48iNFsspHlgAALFhKKFQGH4PHaRnYkkAFkpZKGaImQtF4pxsJlwHlTNEytV6vGmrFEt1+KpBqVKuMav25OMQA)

Comment: do you have an example of a "bug" ? i tried to play with various additional properties in T but didn't a use case

Comment: If the `KeysOfType` type would not be used, and you passed `'v'` into the function it would result in a weird situation.